# Latex: output is in italic

Tags: math, latex, output

If I enter this code in Latex:

```
Using this method, one has to make relative-frequency estimations of P( c ) and P( f_{i} \mid c ), using add-one smoothing.
```

Its output is:

Using this method, one has to make relative-frequency estimations
of P( c ) and P( fi | c), *usingadd−onesmoothing.*

I want it to be like this:

Using this method, one has to make relative-frequency estimations
of P( c ) and P( fi | c), using add-one smoothing.

Anyone knows what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You might find more help for this at [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong forum, there is a tex.stackexchange

You need to indicate mathematical mode with $ signs. Failing that and encountering a mathematical symbol/macro, the interpreter implicitly switched into math mode and found no marker to leave it. Thus kindly use

```
Using this method, one has to make relative-frequency 
estimations of $P( c )$ and $P( f_{i} \mid c )$, 
using add-one smoothing.
```